# Facing issue with Mouse Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web development, so I am taking a Pluralsight course called "Building a Web App with ASP.NET Core RC1, MVC 6, EF7 & AngularJS" by Shawn Wildermuth. In his jQuery module, Shawn has this piece of code that works flawlessly for him:

```
     var main = $("#main");
    main.on("mouseenter", function() {
        main.style = "background-color: #888;";
    });
    main.on("mouseleave", function() {
        main.style = "";
    });
```

I have a div with id="main" on my index.html page, js file is referenced, other jQuery functionality in the same file works, I just can't get this piece of code to work. I know it is not significant, but at this point it is personal. Any suggestions are helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the style property like this. Try the following:

```
var main = $("#main");

main.mouseenter(function() {
  main.css("background-color", "#888");
});
main.mouseleave(function() {
  main.css("background-color", "none");
});
```

Comment: I edited it. Try again. Although it should've worked the first time as well.

Answer (score 3):

As `style` is a property of native DOM element and `main` is a jQuery object. You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) jQuery method to get the desired result.

```
var main = $("#main");
main.on("mouseenter", function() {
    main.css("background-color": "#888");
});
main.on("mouseleave", function() {
    main.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var main = document.getElementById("main");

    main.onmouseenter=function(){
        main.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#888;');
    }; 
    main.onmouseleave=function(){
        main.removeAttribute("style")
    };
```